# Difference between two phase factors

Tags: solid-state-physics

Kittel's book Solid State says that the difference between two phase factors of an incident wave with wave vector **k** and the reflected wave with wave vector **k'**, respectively, is exp(i (**k**-**k'**)•**r**), where **r** is the position Vetorial of an infinitesimal volume element of a solid on which the wave incides. I didn't understand. Shouldn't it be exp(i(**k'**-**k**)•**r**)?  Sorry, but I still don't know how to use mathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your expressions are equivalent because $$-i(\mathbf k -\mathbf k') = -i\mathbf k + i\mathbf k' = i(\mathbf k' -\mathbf k)$$ by the distributive rule.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the minus sign. But I've just edited it. Could you help me again?

Comment: In that case, you would need to look at the sign conventions of the book and what exactly each thing means. To give some context of why this cannot be *too* important, it amounts to a complex conjugation operation, but generally those don’t affect the physics, because they correspond to a mathematical ambiguity: which square root of $-1$ are we calling $i,$ and which $-i$? So the problem only comes when one person using one convention then uses formulas derived with the other convention and adds it to something derived in their convention or so.